# Android Studio - Dúvida sobre comparações de String

Tags: java, android

Estou com o seguinte código

```
static String q1 = "select * from faculdade";

if(edit.getText().toString().equals(q1)) {

    bar.setCurrentPosition(++position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Certa Resposta!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Quando eu digo do jeito que foi declarado na string e aperto o botão, ele executa o que foi pedido.

Porém, se a pessoa der mais de 2 espaços ou então colocar uma virgula junta ou separada, ele não reconhece. Só funciona se eu digitar bem igual o da variável. Como eu faço para contornar isso ? Grato a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode comparar utilizando o método:

1. `.trim()`, para retirar espaços

   ```
   import java.io.*; 
   public class Test {

      public static void main(String args[]) {
             String Str = new String("Hello World");
             System.out.println(Str.trim() ); 

          }
       }
   ```

   printa: HelloWorld
2. `.replaceAll("qualquer caracter aqui", "será substituido pelo carácter que estiver aqui")`

Comment: Você poderia por um exemplo de como eu colocaria ? Eu nunca usei o trim ()

Comment: @LucianaFreireEfelipeCorreia uso: `edit.getText().toString().trim().equals(q1)` ;)

Comment: voltei para agradecer povo. muito obrigado. O replaceAll deu certo.